# How to enable unit of work for each MQ using XSLT in Datapower?

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a requirement where I need to enable unit of work for each queue using XSLT in datapower.
We have MQ as  a frontend and backend.
With 3 MQ Frontside Handlers configured in single MPG service.

I have gone through many Blogs but never found any sample XSLT which shows how to enable unit of work and how to set Backout queue and threshold.

We got this requirement as an implementation to an existing service so have to do this configuration in XSLT.